# angular2 get data before render template

Tags: angular

What I'm trying to do is to get data before render template. I know there are a lot of questions like that, but none of them solve my problem.

I have a component like that

```
<comments [page]="contracts"></comments>
```

I use this component on different pages to show comments section, data goes from backend depends on page parameter. So, I can't use resolver, cause there is no separated page for comments. The second way it to use APP_INITIALIZER, but in that way I can't get @input page, so I can't get the right comments from backend. Any ideas?

My component code

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommentsService } from './comments.service';
import { Comment } from './comment';

@Component({
    selector: 'comments',
    template: window['isMobile'] ? require('./comments-mobile.html') : require('./comments.html'),
    styleUrls: ['./comments.scss']
})
export class CommentsComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() public page: string;
    public comments: Comment[];

    constructor(private commentService: CommentsService) {
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.commentService.getByPage(this.page).subscribe((comments) => {
            this.comments = comments;
            // view still not rendered, so I can't add swipe here
        });
    }
}
```

here is my html

```
<div *ngIf="comments">
    <div *ngFor="let comment of comments"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? Your problem seems a bit too general right now. Maybe showing those attempts of yours. Or a plunkr.

Comment: posted my component code

Comment: right now I just use *ngIf, but it's not good for me. I need to make some manipulations, like add swipe for those elements

Comment: Have you thought about using a secondary route for this? Then, a resolver may be an option. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#secondary-routes

Comment: Unfortunately it's not an option for me

Comment: Why do i think that simply using a boolean would do the job? Wrap the things you don't want to be rendered in a div, create a boolean and set it to true when you actually get the data you need. (Use *ngIf not to render the data before the boolean is set to true)

Comment: yea, actually I do almost the same. The problem is that html elements still not here when parameter set to true. For now as temporary solution I add 1 second timeout, but I don't like this hack